# Кеш в веб приложениях

Tags: веб-программирование, php

Частенько видел в веб приложениях директорию cache (CodeIgniter, Zend, FuelPHP, и т.д.), так же встречался с работой демона memcache на некоторых платформах. Стало интересно как этот механизм работает в веб приложениях, как сейчас принято делать? Ничего толкового, к сожалению, не нагуглил. Если, допустим, надо прикрутить к веб приложению кэш, то с чего мне, как разработчику, начать? Что именно в динамическом веб приложении я могу кэшировать, а что нет? Какие инструменты для работы с кэшем сейчас актуальны? Мог бы посмотреть и код конкретных примеров, но боюсь, что это все будет применимо лишь для того конкретного примера. Кто знает и разбирается в этом посвятите, пожалуйста, в эту технологию?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://myrusakov.ru/php-create-cache.html первая же ссылка по запросу "кэширование страниц php".
На одном из своих сайтов (интернет магазин автозапчастей) пилил велосипед по кешированию.
Логика такова : при обработке url'a проверялось имеется ли в папке кэш страница соответствующая разделу, если существовала то include  уже сформированной страницы, если нет - данные вытягивались из базы, формировалась страница и перед выдачей браузеру сохранялась в файл. При выдаче кешированой страницы запрос занимал меньше секунды, при отсутствии кэша были случаи и до 10 секунд формирования страницы.
Кэшируются уже сформированные страницы в случае их небольшого количества. Ибо если у Вас больше 10 000 страниц на очень посещаемом сайте , место на хостинге уйдёт тупо под кэш.
В таких случаях кешируют только данные( чтобы не обращаться каждый раз к БД) которые передаются шаблонизатору.